# Is there a way to speed up my python program on graphs?

Tags: python, time-limiting

Given with a matrix `NxM`. There are '.' - cells you can visit, and '#' - cells you can't visit. You can only go up, down, right and left (not diagonal). Also given `q` request, in each there are row and column of a cell needed to swap (if cell is '#' change it to '.' and vise versa). For each `q` requests you print 'Yes' if it is possible to get from cell (sx, sy) to cell (tx, ty), and 'No' if not possible. It is givethat (sx, sy) and (tx, ty) are not '#' at any request.

In first line given sx, sy, tx, ty, N, M, q (every one of them is from 1 to 100). In the next N rows given a matrix with '.' being empty cell and '#' being a wall. After these N rows there are q rows with request. Each one is a pair of numbers descrbing x and y position in matrix to swap.

In the output there should be q rows, each having 'Yes' if it is possible to get from start point to target point at te step of the row, or 'No' if it is not possible.

Example:
(Input)

```
1 1 2 3 3 3 2
.##
##.
###
1 2
2 2
```

(Output)

```
No
Yes
```

**Explanation**

After first request the matrix is

```
..#
##.
###
```

After the second request the matrix is

```
..#
#..
###
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the any more inpu examples. However, I have to pass all the unknown test on a website. There I solve all tests right except the two where I got time limit error. Maybe you can see hwo to speed up my code. By the way, the time limit is 0.5 second

My code is here:

```
sx, sy, tx, ty, n, m, q = map(int, input().split())
arr = [[] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    line = input()
    arr[i] = [1 if j=='.' else 0 for j in line]
change = [[] for i in range(q)]
for i in range(q):
    change[i] = list(map(int, input().split()))

def is_path(sx, sy, tx, ty, gr):
    visited = []
    path = False

    def dfs(px, py):
        global path
        if (px, py) == (tx, ty):
            return True
        visited.append([px, py])
        for dx in [1, -1]:
            if -1<py+dx<n and gr[px+dx][py] == 1 and [px+dx, py] not in visited:
                if dfs(px+dx, py):
                    return True
        for dy in [1, -1]:
            if -1<py+dy<m and gr[px][py+dy] == 1 and [px, py+dy] not in visited:
                if dfs(px, py+dy):
                    return True
        return False

    return dfs(sx, sy)

for i in range(q):
    arr[change[i][0]-1][change[i][1]-1] += 1
    arr[change[i][0] - 1][change[i][1] - 1] %= 2

    ans = is_path(sx-1, sy-1, tx-1, ty-1, arr)
    if ans: print('Yes')
    else: print('No')
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Comment: If you don't have any other test cases, you have to make some.  We also expect that you will profile your code -- use a tool or do something to show where your code is slow.  Otherwise, you're asking for a wholesale code review, which is a different site (StackExchange.CodeReview).

Answer (score 1):

The main algorithmic inefficiency is your use of a list for the “visited” set, which leads to quadratic worst-case complexity in the size of the grid. Using `set` would drop that to linear time.

Beyond that, you’d want to exploit the coherency between queries. For instance, if a cell is made traversable then it will not break a path, and if a cell is made non-traversable then it will never create one. You could also use a disjoint set structure to watch for when the connected components containing the start and end cells are joined.